# Nginx: how to set or pass headers in redirect to localhost?

Tags: nginx

I want to pass some headers that are retrieved from one `location` and pass them via a redirect to the user's localhost.  However, I cannot see the headers.  Is this possible and if so, how do I do it?

Here is a location where we add a header then call `rewrite`:

```
location = /proxy-localhost/9000 {
    // in due course, I will pass other headers, but for now let's just pass this
    add_header 'Dummy' "dummy_val";
    rewrite ^ http://localhost:9000;
}
```

However, when I run a simple server using `ncat` on localhost, I don't see a header called `Dummy` in the output when I trigger the `/proxy-localhost` location block via a curl request (I can see the `rewrite` being actioned in the logs, so I know the block is being triggered):

```
$ for i in {1..3}; do echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\nOK" | ncat -vv -l 9000; done
```

Comment: Your `location` block is only interacting with the client (`curl`). `add_header` sends a **response** header to the client, and `rewrite` sends a 3xx response to the client. If you want Nginx to interact with another server, you will need to use `proxy_pass`. If you want to send **request** headers to that server, you will need to use `proxy_set_header`.

Comment: Thanks - I'd naively assumed that headers passed back to the client via `add_header` would then form part of the subsequent request to the rewritten URL.